# How to build a click counter with multiple click values and combine them into a total click value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie and I built this click counter with jquery and it is working great but it seems clunky to me and I want to make my code cleaner. So my question is how can I combine the two click functions into one function and then use the total of the two variables "click1" and "click2" as the value for the variable "sum"? I am assuming one would loop through the separate elements and add their clicks to an array and then add the values stored in the array and assign that as the total, but I am not sure where to start or if that is even possible. I am learning jquery and plain javascript so I can understand suggestions in either syntax. Thank you all!

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/chasereckling/pen/KgArLG?editors=1010

```
<div class="clickButton">
    <button id="updateClick1" type="button">click me</button>
    <span>Number of Clicks: <span class="clickNumber">0</span></span>
</div>

<div class="clickButton">
    <button id="updateClick2" type="button">click me</button>
    <span>Number of Clicks: <span class="clickNumber">0</span></span>
</div>

<div>Total Clicks: <span id="sumClicks">0</span></div>

<script>
    var count1 = 0;
    var count2 = 0;
    var sum = 0;

    $('#updateClick1').click(function() {
      count1++;
      sum++;
      $(this).siblings().children('.clickNumber').html(count1);
      $('#sumClicks').html(sum);
    });

    $('#updateClick2').click(function() {
      count2++;
      sum++;
      $(this).siblings().children('.clickNumber').html(count2);
      $('#sumClicks').html(sum);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var sum = 0;

function clickHandler () {
  var $target = $(this),
      $span = $target.siblings("span").children(".clickNumber"),
      $sum = $("#sumClicks");
  $span.text(parseInt($span.text()) + 1);
  sum += 1;
  $sum.text(sum);
}

$('button[type="button"]').click(clickHandler);
```

Here is codepen:
[sum of clicks](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozQkjz?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code snippet

```js
var count=0;
var sum = 0;
var $sumElement=$('#sumClicks');
sum=parseInt($sumElement.html());
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function() {
  var element=$(this);
  var $clickCount=$(this).siblings().children('.clickNumber');
 
  var clickCountVal=parseInt($clickCount.html());
 clickCountVal++;
  sum++;
  $clickCount.html(clickCountVal);
 $sumElement.html(sum);
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickButton">
  <button id="updateClick1" type="button">click me</button>
  <span>Number of Clicks: <span class="clickNumber">0</span></span>
</div>

<div class="clickButton">
  <button id="updateClick2" type="button">click me</button>
  <span>Number of Clicks: <span class="clickNumber">0</span></span>
</div>

<div>Total Clicks: <span id="sumClicks">0</span></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, it'll be a bit cleaner:

```
<div class="clickButton">
    <button id="updateClick1" type="button">click me</button>
    <span>Number of Clicks: <span class="clickNumber1">0</span></span>
</div>

<div class="clickButton">
   <button id="updateClick2" type="button">click me</button>
   <span>Number of Clicks: <span class="clickNumber2">0</span></span>
</div>

<div>Total Clicks: <span id="sumClicks">0</span></div>



var count = [0,0];

$('#updateClick1').click(function() {
  count[0]++;
  $('.clickNumber1').html(count[0]);
  $('#sumClicks').html(count[0] + count[1]);
});

$('#updateClick2').click(function() {
  count[1]++;
  $('.clickNumber2').html(count[1]);
  $('#sumClicks').html(count[0] + count[1]);
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/s7pw5oqs/1/